# SOLR как искать полный адрес?

Tags: php, solr

Кто либо работал с базой адресов ФИАС?
Дак вот, мы эту базу загрузили в СОЛР коллекцию.
в кратце она имеет формат:

```
ID | тип | название объекта
```

В одной коллекции находятся все объекты, начиная от области, до улицы. Например адрес: Архангельская область, г Архангельск, ул Ломоносова выглядит так:

```
294277aa-e25d-428c-95ad-46719c4ddb44  | обл  | Архангельская
06814fb6-0dc3-4bec-ba20-11f894a0faf5  | г    | Архангельск
5d5ef54d-e11e-41f0-bc36-42d22467019e  | п-кт | Ломоносова
```

Вот и вопрос, как искать в таблице полные адреса? не просто "архангельск" а полную строку: Архангельская область, г Архангельск, ул Ломоносова? 
Я строку чищу от припенаний и стоп слов

как можно искать при таком расположении данных в таблице? может у солр есть какая то фишка?

Comment: В ФИАС, для построения полного адреса нужно учитывать еще **parentguid**, **previd**, **nextid**. **parentguid** - используется как раз для того чтобы понять, что улица к примеру принадлежит какому то городу, а город какому то региону, а **previd**, **nextid** чтобы понять насколько данный объект адреса актуальный и не нужно ли использовать его следующую версию

Comment: это все понятно. может я как то не правильно ищу в солр? я ищу всю строку сразу q=*Полный адрес*. а потом то что нашло из того слепляю результат

Comment: может надо как то разбивать? хотя как тут правильно разбить по разному могут ввести

Comment: Честно говоря с СОЛР не работал, но делал подобное на sphinx, то есть итоговая коллекция для индекса у меня выглядела примерно так: 
**randomId, regionId, cityId, streetId, address**

то есть в вашем случае выглядело бы так
**1244353, 294277aa-e25d-428c-95ad-46719c4ddb44,
06814fb6-0dc3-4bec-ba20-11f894a0faf5, 5d5ef54d-e11e-41f0-bc36-42d22467019e, Архангельская Архангельск
Ломоносова**

Поиск соответственно проходил по полю address, а из найденной записи уже вытягивались id составляющих

Comment: тоесть все же надо создавать отдельную коллекцию для поиска с полным адресом так сказать.

Comment: можно как то ее сгенерировать средствами солр? согласно родительских ID или опять что то мутить внешне программировать

Comment: По СОЛРу не подскажу, для своих целей я использовал связку sphinx  и mysql то есть сам фиас хранился в мускуле, в нем же строилась таблица, в которой были все варианты адресов, как описывал вышел, а сфинкс уже индексировал эту таблицу. Сама таблица заполнялась хранимой процедурой.